# Formula to Use VLOOKUP on the filtered Data only

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to use VLOOKUP between 2 Excel files Where i need to search the value of a specific column from Another Excel file, in the Another sheet (Sheet2), I am suppose to use filter based on a specific value.

For Eg:

**Excel 1**

```
Col1     Col2

ID223    Active
ID225    Not Active
ID667    Static
ID345    Active
ID678    Active
```

**Excel 2**

```
Col1     Col2

ID223    
ID225    
ID623    
ID345    
ID678
```

**Expected Output (Excel 2)**

```
Col1     Col2
    
 ID223    Eligible
 ID225    
 ID623    
 ID345    Eligible
 ID678    Eligible



Code I have been using:

= VLOOKUP(A2, [Excel 2.XLSX]Sheet1!$A:$B,1,0)

I have also Tried

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2, [Excel 2.XLSX]Sheet1!$A:$B,1,FALSE)),"", "Eligible"
```

Comment: did you try COUNTIFS to see if both exist in the same row?

Comment: @ScottCraner Please Suggest how to use that formula in this case.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I have tried using IF Condition as well in the formula but its not working, Not getting how to use the IF condition on the another Excel

Comment: That's a classic: `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(1,('[Excel 1.XLSX]Sheet1'!$A:$A=A2)*('[Excel 1.XLSX]Sheet1'!$B:$B="Active"),0)),"","Eligible")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ScottCraner suggested, use `COUNTIFS` to see if both exist in the same row.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,$D1,$B:$B,"Active")>0,"Eligible","")
```

The first `COUNTIFS` criteria `$A:$A` looks up the ID `$D1` and counts how many times the ID appears. The second criteria `$B:$B` looks for `"Active"` and counts how many times it appears and both the first and second criteria must have a match for it to count.

`>0` is there in the `IF` statement so that you can change the result from `1` to whatever you want